# How to access library dependencies at build-time in SBT/Scala build?

Tags: scala, build, sbt, metaprogramming

For example, suppose I have a file `project/CodeGeneration.scala` that generates "managed" source-code, and suppose that object (`CodeGeneration`) needs to leverage a third-party library -- say [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/)...

```
import org.jsoup._

object CodeGeneration {
  def generateCode = /* Generate code using jsoup... */
}
```

Simply adding a line for `jsoup` to your `libraryDependencies` in `build.sbt` doesn't do the trick; it leads to a compilation error complaining about the missing `jsoup` object/namespace.

So, (how) can one access this dependency from "meta" code -- code that generates other code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the solution is to leverage sbt's "recursive" nature, and put an additional `build.sbt` file in the `project` directory. So, for example, `project/build.sbt` might look like this:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.jsoup" % "jsoup" % "1.11.2"
```

There's more detail [in sbt's official documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Organizing-Build.html).